# Testing for a TypeError using Typescript and Jasmine

Tags: typescript, jasmine

What I'm attempting to do is write unit tests in Typescript for an existing library of functions we have had for a a while that was written using plain JS. All of our page logic is in plain JS too. Some of these functions threw exceptions when given the wrong types as an input. For instance:

```
Collection.pluck([{"a":1},{"a":2}], "a") // Pulls the values out of a list of objects
> [1, 2]
```

So the second argument there should be a string, the property name you want to get the values for. Within the pluck function there is type checking verifying that an array of objects has been passed in, when this fails it throws a TypeError.

So to write a test verifying that the correct type of object was passed in I would write it like in plain JS:

```
expect(function(){ Collection.pluck([{"a":1},{"a":2}], 0); }).toThrowError(TypeError);
```

However in my declaration file I have it defined as such:

```
declare namespace Collection {
    function pluck(obj: Object, propertyName: string): any;
}
```

So when I go to write the unit test using TS I get a compile error, obviously:
[image: TS compile error]

So how do I do what I want without any changes to the function? Is there something I can configure in TS to ignore this for this file only?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send the second argument of your test as string if you are in a position to change the test.

```
expect(function(){ Collection.pluck([{"a":1},{"a":2}], '0'); }).toThrowError(TypeError);
```

UPDATE:
You are using typescript which already does type checking at compilation phase (transpilation to JS ) as you are specifying the type in function declaration. Technically your code already passes the test case. 
If you really need type verification through unit testing you should do for those cases where type is set as 'any' as these will not be checked during compilation.
OR check here
[Unittesting in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695934/unittesting-in-typescript)

Comment: While that would stop the TS error, it would fail the test because I am testing if it is explicitly a string. Also I do other tests like these where I am checking for objects, arrays, functions, etc where I am also having the same issue.

Comment: I guess I could use 'any'. It's just weird because it doesn't reflect the internal workings of the function when using TS, but it's not like we can begin using TS everywhere in our application so this "error" in the definition would not be seen by anyone but me. What matters is that the compiled JS remains the same and continues to throw TypeError's.